# Build a menu tree from slash separated keys

Tags: python

I have a list of objects, like this (simplified):

```
[
    MenuItem(key="Menu/SomeDropdown/Hello", title="Hello", url="hello.html"),
    MenuItem(key="Menu/SomeDropdown/SomeMore", title="Some More", url="bla.html"),
    MenuItem(key="Menu/Contact", title="Contact", url="contact.html"),
    MenuItem(key="Menu/About", title="About", url="about.html"),
]
```

In reality this objects are Django models so they contain a bunch of stuff.

I want to render this as follows:

```
- Menu
-- SomeDropdown
--- Hello (using .url and .title)
--- SomeMore (using .url and .title)
-- Contact (using .url and .title)
-- About (using .url and .title)
```

Comment: Do you mean literally render that text, or render in HTML in Django in some way?

Comment: I'm going to render it with <li> elements in Django indeed.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could override the `RenderTree` call in the `anytree` library to style your tree.

Here's some code to construct a tree from sample data:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import anytree

o = [
    {
        'key' : 'Menu/SomeDropdown/Hello',
        'title' : 'Hello',
        'url' : 'hello.html',
    },
    {
        'key' : 'Menu/SomeDropdown/SomeMore',
        'title' : 'Some More',
        'url' : 'bla.html',
    },
    {
        'key' : 'Menu/Contact',
        'title' : 'Contact',
        'url' : 'contact.html',
    },
    {
        'key' : 'Menu/About',
        'title' : 'About',
        'url' : 'about.html'
    }
]

root = anytree.Node('root')
for oe in o:
    oek = oe['key']
    oet = oe['title']
    oeu = oe['url']
    es = oek.split('/')
    parent = root
    el = len(es) - 1
    for i,v in enumerate(es):
        p = anytree.search.find(parent, lambda node: node.name == v)
        if not p:
            v_node = anytree.Node(v, parent=parent)
            if i == el:
                v_node.title = oet
                v_node.url = oeu
            parent = v_node
        else:
            parent = p

print(anytree.RenderTree(root))
```

The printed result would require your styling, but it is organized into a tree and has the desired attributes for lookup:

```
Node('/root')
└── Node('/root/Menu')
    ├── Node('/root/Menu/SomeDropdown')
    │   ├── Node('/root/Menu/SomeDropdown/Hello', title='Hello', url='hello.html')
    │   └── Node('/root/Menu/SomeDropdown/SomeMore', title='Some More', url='bla.html')
    ├── Node('/root/Menu/Contact', title='Contact', url='contact.html')
    └── Node('/root/Menu/About', title='About', url='about.html')
```

If you don't want to use `RenderTree`, you could just as well iterate over nodes of the tree, using the depth of the node to decide how to render list item bullet depth, or otherwise convert this into an HTML `ol` or `ul` element in Django.

Hopefully this gets you started.